# Binary Bits matching

Tags: probability

Given two binary strings $X$ and $Y$ of same length $n$, what is the probability that we choose a random index $j$ such that $X_j \neq Y_j$ and there is (at least) another index $k\neq j$ such that $X_k = Y_k$? Is this solved by inclusion/exclusion?

Comment: You may assume that $j=0$ and then you just have to calculate the probability for $X_k = Y_k$ for some $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ and multiply that with the probability $X_0 \neq Y_0$ - so there is no need for an inclusion/exclusion argument.

Comment: Binary bits? What are bits, and what are binary bits?

Comment: @user155124 Since you apparently understand the problem statement, would you please explain what it means? What do you mean by "the probability $X_0\ne Y_0$, the strings $X$ and $Y$ are given, aren't they?

Comment: I understand the question as follows "Given $j \in \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$.What is the probability that two sequences $(X_0,X_1, \ldots,X_{n-1}),(Y_0,Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1}) \in 2^n$ have a different $j$-th coordinate and at least one $k$-th coordinate in common."

Comment: What @user155124 said